# Easiest way to get a random number, that isn't in substring?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to keep track of what values in a substring has been used, and then pick one of the values that haven't been used once already.

The idea is a hint system, that doesn't just repeat the same hints.

Quick example:

```
str = [
  'value1',
  'value2',
  'value3'
];
usedStr = [
  '0'
];
```

So in that example I need to either get 'value2' or 'value3'.

Hope that makes sense. Any different approaches are appreciated as well, I'm fairly new to coding. Thanks.

***EDIT:***

I need the code to take account of that the usedStr's could be 0 and 3 for example. Math.random wouldn't work...

And also the used values are stored in localStorage.

Comment: Start at looking up `Math.random`

Comment: I know how to get a random value like Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length), but that doesn't take account that the used substrings could be 0, 2 and 4, and I need it to do that.

Comment: sorry, it's just that you've done nothing in the question to show that - do you know about array filter?

Comment: That's alright, I'll edit that in. And no, I've not heard of that, but I'll take a look. :)

Comment: Well, there you go - I didn't know what you did or didn't know :p

Comment: `Math.random wouldn't work` yes, it would, if you do it right

Comment: I don't see how? Only if I used the hint str chronological, right?

Comment: erm - a perfectly OK (given the original question) answer was deleted after you made the following bizarre statement *`Would this code be compatible ES5? As chrome extensions aren't ES6`* - this is completely wrong

Comment: I apologize. I don't even know the differences between ES5 and ES6, as mentioned, I am new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Give this one a go :

```js
while(1==1){
  var item = str[Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length)];
  if (!usedStr.includes(item)){
    console.log(item);
    usedStr.push(item)
    break;
  }else if (usedStr.length==str.length){
    console.log("usedStr is full");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this may work. I'll have to look at it tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: U're welcome, I hope u accept my answer if u find it helpful ;)

Comment: this doesn't save the newly used index in `usedStr` as per edited question

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX for notifying me, I fixed it and I hope u left the downvote :)

Comment: Yes, that's why I downvoted (not your fault though, the original question was vague on such important details)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that why I assumed that usedStr is updated by another part until I noticed ur comment and the edited question, so thank you and would a upvote so much to ask ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
// read already used indexes from localStorage
var usedStr = localStorage.usedStr || [];

//create an array of all possible index values
var indexesToUse = [...Array(str.length).keys()];

if (usedStr.length < str.length)  //if not all have been used, remove the used ones
    indexesToUse = indexesToUse.filter(val=>!~usedStr.indexOf(val));

//pick a random value from the index array
var index = indexesToUse[0|Math.random()*indexesToUse.length];

console.log('Today\'s random hint is: ' + str[index]);

//save the used index in localStorage
usedStr.push(index);
localStorage.usedStr = usedStr;
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea: Shuffle your hints and the beginning and then `pop` one by one.

```js
var hints = []; //make it global
var usedHints = [];

function getHintsFromStorage() {
  //your logic here
  return ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
}

function saveHintsToStorage() {
  //save hints and usedHints here
}

function resetHints() {
  //receive hints somehow
  hints = getHintsFromStorage()
    .sort(function() {
      return Math.random() < 0.5; //shuffle
    });
}

function getHint() {
  if (hints.length > 0) {
    var hint = hints.pop();
    document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = hint; //use once and throw
    usedHints.push(hint);
    saveHintsToStorage();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = 'no more hints';
  }
}
resetHints();
```

```html
<div id="hint"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="getHint()">Get Hint</button>
<button type="button" onclick="resetHints()">Reset Hints (for test purpose)</button>
```

Comment: Hm. I might be over complicating my code. But this would work, as using one hint per day, so for each day it needs to be different... And the hints are located in the code, but the used values are stored in localStorage.Thanks for the suggestions anyhow.

Comment: `the used values are stored in localStorage` - an important point not mentioned in the question